# confusion of letrec, Scheme

Tags: scheme, letrec

I am struggling the difference between let, letrec, let* ...
since scheme is not my primary programming language, my memory is not existing for long time.. 
I have this function.. now I am very confusing with letrec here.. this is again recursion.that I can understand...but can't make connection enough in this code.. (maybe still confuse about recursion)
can someone explain why here need letrec

```
(define myFunc
  (lambda (start end res func)
    (letrec ((func:rec_func
              (lambda (x i y)
                (if (>= i start)
                    (func:rec_func (cons i x) (- i res) (cons (func i) y))  ;; line6
                    (cons x (cons y '()))))))                               ;; line7
      (func:rec_func '() end '()))))
```

(edited)
what I understand it's tail recursion

-> [Q1] Does it tail recursion?

-> [Q2] then, should use always letrec for tail recursion?

this function returns the lists of x, y with boundaries of start, end
so it checks index i is inside boundaries , if yes, then do line 6

-> [Q3]then, what does line6 ? I can't get the line6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Q1]** Does it tail recursion?

**Answer** Yes, it does tail recursion.

**[Q2]** then, should use always letrec for tail recursion?

**Answer** There are two ways of interpreting your question.

1. Should we always use `letrec` for tail recursion? I don't think you meant to ask this. But ...

   The answer is no. Top level lambda functions can also be used for tail recursion.
2. Should `letrec` always use tail recursion?

   The answer to that is: It's better for any recursive function to be tail recursive. If you can, you should make it tail recursive.

**[Q3]** then what does line6 ?

The code at line 6 performs the recursive call.

Let's say `start` is `0`, `end` is `5`, and `res` is `1`. In the first call to `func:rec_func`, `x` is the empty list `()`, `i` is `5`, and `y` is the empty list `()`.

When the first recursive function is called at line 6, the arguments are `(cons i x)`, `(- i res)`, and `(cons (func i) y)`, which evaluate to: `(5)`, `4`, and `((func 5)`.

In the next iteration, the arguments are `(4 5)`, `3`, and `((func 4) (func 5))`.

It continues until `i` becomes less than `start`. Then the recursion stops with the result `((0 1 2 3 4 5) ((func 0) (func 1) (func 2) (func 3) (func 4) (func 5)))`

The code at line 7 is executed when the terminating criterion for the recursion is met, which is when `(>= i start)` is false.

Answer (score 8):

The difference with letrec, let and let* is when they do the declaration available to the program.

```
(letrec ((X (you could use X here))
         (Y (you could use X here too))
         )
     (X also is available here)
)


(let   ((X (nope, X isn't declared yet))
         (Y (in fact, no declaration body will see X))
         )
     (But X is available here)
)


(let* ((X (X isn't available here))
         (Y (but you could use it here))
         )
     (X also is available here)
)
```

*To recap:*

1. The scope of a variable declared with letrec is ALL inside of the body of letrec. The compiler do some magic so the references are replaced after the declarations are over.
2. The scope of a variable declared with let* are all expresions in the scope of let* after the declaration of the variable.
3. And the scope of a variable declared with let is just the body of let, not the declaration parts.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: So if I understand correctly all but letrec are superfluous?

Comment: Not really, because the expression in let or let* can bind with a variable with the same name outside, that is not possible with letrec. (But it doesn't mean that it is a good practice). Most code I have seen use let or let* because clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, this construct requires `letrec` rather than `let` or `let*` because the body of `func:rec_func` refers to itself.  If you used `let` or `let*` here, the symbol `func:rec_func` within the nested lambda would be bound to any definition visible *outside* the top-level form, or undefined if there was no such definition - neither is what you want.